# Covariance between two matricies in MATLAB

Tags: matlab, matrix, covariance

I have two matricies, **X** and **Y**, with each column representing multiple realizations of a random variable;

```
X = [x_11  x_21  .... x_n1
     x_12  x_22  .... x_n2
      .     .    ....  .
      .     .    ....  .
     x_1m  x_2m  .... x_nm]
```

And where Y is a function of X: Y = f(X)

```
Y = [y_11  y_21  .... y_n1
     y_12  y_22  .... y_n2
      .     .    ....  .
      .     .    ....  .
     y_1m  y_2m  .... y_nm]
```

I want to find the covariance matrix between the variables x_n and y_n;

```
E{(X - E{Y}) * (Y - E{Y})^H}
```

Where ()^H denotes the [Hermitian Transpose](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conjugate_transpose) of the vector

In matlab, when I run `cov(X,Y)` on the matricies, (each 1000 trials of 20 variables) I only get a 2x2 matrix back, which leads me to believe that it is treating each matrix as a single "variable" somehow.  If I concatenate the two matricies and call `cov` on the result:

```
cov( [X Y] )
```

I get a 40x40 matrix, with the result of `cov( X )` in the top left, the result of `cov( Y )` in the bottom right, and the matrix I want in the top right and bottom left, but is there a way to calculate this without having to resort to this?

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`cov(X,Y)` is equivalent to `cov([x(:) y(:)])`. But `[x(:) y(:)]` is 20000 by 2 for you, and `cov()` treats rows as observations and columns as dimensions, so you get a 2 by 2 covariance matrix.

I would just implement it myself by the definition:

```
bsxfun(@minus,x,mean(x))'*bsxfun(@minus,y,mean(y))/(size(x,1)-1)
```

If you have an older version of matlab that doesn't support `bsxfun()`, just use `repmat()`.

Comment: Works like a charm, and as an added bonus, I've never used bsxfun before!  Thank you very much for this tip!